# Programa convertir un flotante a entero, pero conservando los fraccionales

Tags: python

Este es el programa que he hecho:

```
def flot_int(Num):
    if isinstance(Num, float):
         return conversion(Num)
    else:
        return 'Error: entrada debe ser un flotante'
def conversion(Num):
    if Num-int(Num) == 0.0:
        return int(Num)*10
    else:
        convertidor = Num*10**(len(str(Num-int(Num)))-2)
        return int(convertidor)
```

Pero al realizar una operacion como 3.1-3 da como resultado: 0.10000000000000009, en lugar del 0.1 que quiero.

Cómo puedo resolver este problema?

Comment: Si te es importante conservar la presición en tus cuentas con decimales puedes usar el modulo [decimal](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/decimal.html)

Answer (score 1):

Se trata de un problema bastante común que sucede en gran cantidad de lenguajes de programación. Es debido a que con la representación en coma flotante (*floating point*), hay ciertos números que no se pueden representar exactamente.

Hay ejemplos bastante curiosos.

```py
print(0.1)
print(0.1**2)
print(0.1+0.1+0.1 - 0.3)
#0.1
#0.010000000000000002
#5.551115123125783e-17
```

Y también hay que tener mucho cuidado al comparar valores `float`.

```py
print(0.1**2 == 0.01)
#False
```

Podrías usar la función `round`, pero ten cuidado no vaya a ser que un futuro te de problemas. El `1` indica el número de elementos decimales para redondear.

```py
x = 3.1-3
print(round(x,1))
```

Answer (score 0):

No se si sea de ayuda, recuerdo que python tiene la la funcion format(), si no es como deseas puedes buscar sobre esa función.

Lo que puedes hacer es darle formato a la salida:

```
print (3.1 - 3)     
print ("{0:.1f}".format(3.1-3))
```

Salida:

```
0.10000000000000009  
0.1
```

También exite la función round() solo que hay que tener cuidado porque puede que redondee como  no esperabas el valor

```
resultado = round(3.1 - 3, 1)
print(3.1 - 3)
print(resultado)
```

Salida:

```
0.10000000000000009
0.1
```